# How to fix error of two bundle id in my mac project

Tags: swift, macos, store

My mac application project has two compiled binaries and the Sqlite mac framework. Each of these three items has its own info. plist

this is the plist of the main binary
[image: this is the plist of the main binary]

this is the plist of the second binary working for the autorun function(the function works successfully)
[image: this is the plist of the second binary]

plist framework SQLite Mac
[image: plist framework SQLite Mac]

and here is the error that gives validate app:
[image: error Mac app store validate]

All identifier, profiles, bundle id are registered in the developer profile, as everything is written in the settings General, Signing & Capabilities and other items, but clearly something is wrong I specify! I can't send apps to Mac AppStore for three days! Help!

Comment: "Each of these three items has its own info. plist"  For what!?

Comment: Otherwise, the project does not compile and displays errors that there are not enough settings items... in any case, I did not create them myself - the second binary must be signed to send and the sql framework also requires a signature from the cocoapods source code

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself! It was necessary to remove the Bundle identifier and bundlenames for the application framework in all windows, and it was also necessary to remove the line in build settings - the key of the Framework search path parameter